# Hive Integer column returns NULL value even though data is in integer format

Tags: hive, hiveql

When I query a table, interger column is returning NULL value but that field is having correct integer data. I tried cast(intcolumn as string,varchar,bigint) but then it is returning NULL only. Can somebody help how to get the data displayed

Comment: can you show us what your data looks like ?

Comment: I resolved it. I was trying to change the column type to string but due to permission it did not change. I created another table in same format with string and it worked